# Content-Security-Policy not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-cloudfront, cdn, content-security-policy

I have an angular application for which I am receiving following `Content Security Policy` error.

```
video.es.js:32051 Refused to create a worker from 'blob:https:/mysubdomain.mycompany.com/ff064232-41e8-4c21-82fe-4b523e4eeae1' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src https: 'unsafe-inline'". 
Note that 'worker-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

(anonymous) @ video.es.js:32051
MasterPlaylistController @ video.es.js:50112
src @ video.es.js:53476
... (lines turncated)
core.js:6210 ERROR DOMException: Failed to construct 'Worker': Access to the script at 'blob:https:/mysubdomain.mycompany.com/ff064232-41e8-4c21-82fe-4b523e4eeae1' is denied by the document's Content Security Policy.
    at new <anonymous> (https:/mysubdomain.mycompany.com/modules-presentation-presentation-module.js:39448:40)
    at new MasterPlaylistController (https:/mysubdomain.mycompany.com/modules-presentation-presentation-module.js:57509:24)
    at VhsHandler.src (https:/mysubdomain.mycompany.com/modules-presentation-presentation-module.js:60873:38)
    at Object.handleSource (https:/mysubdomain.mycompany.com/modules-presentation-presentation-module.js:61403:14)
    at Html5._Tech.setSource (https:/mysubdomain.mycompany.com/modules-presentation-presentation-module.js:17126:30)
    at new Html5 (https:/mysubdomain.mycompany.com/modules-presentation-presentation-module.js:27067:13)
    at Player.loadTech_ (https:/mysubdomain.mycompany.com/modules-presentation-presentation-module.js:30212:18)
    at Player.src_ (https:/mysubdomain.mycompany.com/modules-presentation-presentation-module.js:32652:12)
    at https:/mysubdomain.mycompany.com/modules-presentation-presentation-module.js:32557:25
    at setSourceHelper (https:/mysubdomain.mycompany.com/modules-presentation-presentation-module.js:17492:5)
```

Even though I have added `Content Security` headers in my html file, it seems the browsers are not recognizing it. Here is my `index.html` file:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ITeaserApp</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/favicon.svg">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src http: https: data: blob: 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; worker-src http: https: data: blob: 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';">
</head>
<body>
  <my-app-root></my-app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to set both `default-src` and `worker-src` policies below as per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP).

I don't receive this error when I am running this code locally (http://localhost:4200), but only when I am delivering the app via CDN (hosted on Cloudfront, backed by S3).

Please let me know if I am missing something or if I have to have Cloudfront setting that might resolve this.

Comment: Looks like you already published Content Security Policy header via [lambda@edge](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/adding-http-security-headers-using-lambdaedge-and-amazon-cloudfront/). In this case a second CSP via meta tag will not relax the first CSP. You have to add `blob:` into lambda@edge CSP header.

Comment: @granty, you were correct, We had lambda@edge configured which was adding CSP overriding the my CSP in `index.html`. Thank you!